# Android SMS inbox unread count issues

Tags: android, sms

I have created a little Android application that reacts to incoming SMS messages. The issue is that I cannot seem to be able to reliably get the number of unread messages in the inbox.

Here's a bare minimum class to illustrate the issue. Sometimes it prints "Got SMS! Unread count: 0" and sometimes it prints "Got SMS! Unread count: 1". To me it would appear more logical if whenever the program flow entered that command the unread count would always be at least one. I have been testing this by sending SMS messages from one emulator to another (you can do that by sending the messages to the emulator number -- say, 5554).

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onReceive", "Got something: "+intent.getAction());
    if (!SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("onReceive", "Returning.");
        return;
    }
    Log.d("onReceive", "Got SMS! Unread count: " + getNumberOfUnreadMessages(context));
    // Do stuff
}

public int getNumberOfUnreadMessages(Context context) {
    final Uri SMS_INBOX_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor inboxCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX_URI, null, "read = 0", null, null);
    int unreadMessagesCount = inboxCursor.getCount();
    inboxCursor.close();
    return unreadMessagesCount;
}
}
```

And finally, here's the relevant part from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

How do I get the correct number of unread messages?

**Edit/Add:** Alternatively, if it's a case of the broadcast being sent before the SMS is saved, is there a way to subscribe the app to listen for the event of a new SMS message being saved into the inbox?

Comment: I had the same issue with broadcast receiver. It seems that when the broadcast checks the unread count from cursor, the new message is missing, like if the broadcast was triggered before the message was stocked in database, so it gives the bad count. I just did like inboxCursor.getCount() + 1;

Comment: @Samet Yep, that's how it seems. What did you do about it, then? How do I make the broadcast trigger only after the message is saved into the database? Note that it does not fail constantly, only about every other time or so, so `getCount() + 1` is not a good solution.

Comment: but you should avoid getCount() which is very slow, I had the experience, with some more messages, the app will hang. You should just create an int count = 1; outside the loop, and while moving in the cursor, do count ++; that way it it takes milliseconds instead of seconds,and I think you will get the true count.

Comment: I never tried to search why this happens, I'm not sure but you could maybe change your broadcast's priority so it will trigger last. I think this problem is due the default sms app, inserting the new sms in the database after your broadcast, like you didn't insert anything in the database and just retrieved the sms unread count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to observe sms inbox, use a ContentObserver like this :

OnCreate() :

```
contentObserver observer = new contentObserver(handler);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), true, observer);
```

Create a new inner class or outter class:

```
public class contentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public contentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        // you can use a handler if you want or directly do everythinh onChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        // Do your stuff here
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
}
```

OnDestroy() :

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
```

Comment: Thanks, that might be a better way of doing it than my current one. I'll decide on accepting this answer once I've had the opportunity to try this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  It seems the BroadcastReceiver is triggered when you actually receive the text message.  This is can be before the SmsManager writes the message to the database.

Either wait a few seconds after you receive the broadcast or manually keep a count of how many times you receive the broadcast and increase the count, save to private SharedPreferences and decrease count when user reads the message.